# java swing button action

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm begginer on java.I want to desing a craps game by using java swing(GUI). I got the algorithm of the game but i have a problem with GUI design.I have 4 label and textbox for rolling results and summations and one button for rolling e.g 
label1: 4-5 textBox1: 9 
  label2: 3-3 textbox2: 6 
button
I want to do like this:  when i click the button first time, label1 and textbox1 change; i click again, label2 and textbox2 change. How can I do it like in this order?
Here is the GUI of my project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwNom.png

```
 int  n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
 int  n1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
 private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       


            jLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(n) + "-" + Integer.toString(n1));
            jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(n+n1));}
```

Comment: You need some kind of flag to determine whose go it is, maybe a `boolean` or an `int` and some modular maths (ie `(flag % 2) == 0` for even numbers)

Comment: I added my code for first action. Can you help me for second label? How can I do it? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
int n1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
boolean label2 = false;

private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (!label2) {
        jLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(n) + "-" + Integer.toString(n1));
        jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(n + n1));
        label2=true;
    } else if (label2) {
        jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(n) + "-" + Integer.toString(n1));
        jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(n + n1));
        label2=false;
    }
}
```

the boolean flag should work correctly. now it should first edit label 1 and then label 2 and after that again label 1